# :through relations in rails: query by attribute in related table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following Rails definition:

```
Class Book
  string title
  has_many readings
  has_many users, :through => :readings

Class Reader
  int rating
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :user

Class User
  has_many readings
  has_many books, through => :readings
```

No I want to query like this:

Give me all readings ratings for user A that have book.title = "test"

Could you help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This will give you an array of all ratings for a book 
with title "test" which was read by user with name "A"

```
User.find_by_name("A").books.find_by_title("test").readings.map{|r| r.rating }
```

But to be honest, I'm really not sure if this is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can include the related models and use these as parameters.

```
Users.find(
  :all,
  :include => {:readings => :books},
  :conditions => "books.title = ? AND etc"
)
```

Obviously not 100% correct, but should give you the right idea.